# Vulnerabilities every time i use create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

[image]

63 vulnerabilities when using create-react-app how do i fix this?

ive ran npm audit fix, and it fixes 0 out of 63 vulnerabilities

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using latest version of node.js and that's why facing issue. The current version of node has miscellaneous bug.

Using older version of node.js will solve the issue.

You can keep looping on this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6443) and use the latest release after it is fixed.

Or, you can also exclude low vulnerabilities dependency like below as mentioned in the issue:

```
npm audit --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org --parseable | grep -V
 https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/786 | wc -l
```

Alternatively, you can use [npm-audit-resolver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-audit-resolver) which is good rather than excluding the dependencies.

Answer (score -2):

As it says `npm audit fix` would fix these for you. This would update the packages. You might want to check the changelogs of these packages.

For your learning purposes, you could ignore the warning, as this has **low severity**.

EDIT 1:
Since `npm audit fix` isn't fixing this problem. I would strongly suggest overlooking this warning as these are only development packages and it should not affect your production build in any way.

Highly likely create-react-app would fix these issues in next releases.

Comment: Author told in his question that this command doesn't fix issue for him

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I didn't see.  I think the author added that part after I answered.